# How to put Vue.js in production mode using webpack 2.7?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I've got an existing code base in which Vue.js has performance problems. I also see this notice in the browser console:

[image]

so I guess an easy fix could be to put Vue into production mode.

In [the suggested link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html) I try to follow the instructions for webpack. We're on Webpack version 2.7 (current stable version is 4.20). In the instructions it says that in Webpack 3 and earlier, you’ll need to use `DefinePlugin`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
  ]
}
```

So in my package.json I've got a build script defined:

[image]

To build for production I run `yarn run build` and it runs a `build.js` file ([paste here](https://pastebin.com/faMLBUGe)) which in turn calls `webpack.base.conf.js` ([paste here](https://pastebin.com/yizyE1vy)) and `webpack.prod.conf.js` ([paste here](https://pastebin.com/ZtXp3uC2)).

As you can see in the paste I use the `DefinePlugin` as suggested by the docs.

I also found a file called `vue-loader.conf.js` ([paste here](https://pastebin.com/G0XRy4Sv)) and to be sure I also added the `DefinePlugin` in there as well.

I can run `yarn run build` which ends without errors, but when serve the site over Apache and open the browser it still shows the notification that we're in development mode.

To be sure it actually uses the files created by webpack I completely removed the folder `/public/webpack/` and checked that the webinterface didn't load correctly without the missing files and then built again to see if it loaded correctly after the command finished. So it does actually use the files built by this webpack process. But Vue is actually not created in production mode.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you serving the build? `cd dist`, `http-server` or equivalent?

Comment: @HiramK.Hackenbacker - I use apache on an Ubuntu 16.04 server

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The changes you made should enable production mode. I recommend comparing your setup to [`vuejs-templates/webpack@fb39683`](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/fb39683/template) (the commit before the version bump to webpack 3.x).

Comment: You said **but when I open the browser...**, I was wondering how you were starting up the production build, as (see warning after build) you would need to run a server in the `dist` folder. I usually do it with `http-server` which I installed globally with npm. Sorry if you have already knew that, just thought I'd check.

Comment: Like tony19 I have no problem running the production build. I compared your configs - there are diffs, but essentially are the same as mine.

Comment: why don't you just upgrade the webpack ? could be simpler than debugging the quirks of obsolete versions.

Comment: are you using trying to resolve any `alias`es ? could you link './webpack.base.conf' ?

Comment: @darklightcode - If with `alias`es you mean Linux softlinks I'm pretty sure I'm not trying to resolve any. I added a paste of `webpack.base.conf.js` to the question. Here it is as well: https://pastebin.com/yizyE1vy

Comment: You need to add a alias to your build webpack config [check a question here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5063#issuecomment-301238826)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be in your 'webpack.base.conf.js' as i suspected, thank you for sharing it, upon searching i've found an issue resolving your 'production not being detected' problem on github [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5063)

The solution requires that you change `'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue'` to `'vue$': vue/dist/vue.min` in production.

You will find the original answer as:

> @ozee31 This alias **'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue'** cause the problem, use **vue/dist/vue.min** in production environment.